# How to merge duplicate object parent items in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-merge

I want to merge objects in array so that objects with the same id (which is a child object) can sum the total_price and total_quantity values.
Here is my data array:

```
var data = [
        {
            "_id": {
                "month": 5,
                "year": 2021
            },
            "total_price": 145111500,
            "total_quantity": 7
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2021
            },
            "total_price": 98386000,
            "total_quantity": 5
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2021
            },
            "total_price": 32500000,
            "total_quantity": 3
        }
    ]
```

I want to merge objects that have the duplicate "_id". Here is the output result:

```
var merge = [
        {
            "_id": {
                "month": 5,
                "year": 2021
            },
            "total_price": 145111500,
            "total_quantity": 7
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2021
            },
            "total_price": 130886000,
            "total_quantity": 8
        }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { "_id": { "month": 5, "year": 2021 }, "total_price": 145111500, "total_quantity": 7 },
  { "_id": { "month": 6, "year": 2021 }, "total_price": 98386000, "total_quantity": 5 },
  { "_id": { "month": 6, "year": 2021 }, "total_price": 32500000, "total_quantity": 3 }
];

const res = [...
  // iterate over the list
  data.reduce((map, item) => {
    // construct key from _id
    const key = `${item._id.month}-${item._id.year}`;
    // get prev map value of key if exists
    const prev = map.get(key);
    // update map, if prev not found, set value as item, or update it with the added values
    map.set(
      key, 
      !prev 
        ? item 
        : { ...item, total_price: prev.total_price + item.total_price, total_quantity: prev.total_quantity + item.total_quantity }
    );
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  // return map values
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = [];
var merge =  [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj = data[i];
  let dupId = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
    if (ids[j]["month"] == obj["_id"]["month"] && ids[j]["year"] == obj["_id"]["year"]) {
      merge[j]["total_price"] += obj["total_price"];
      merge[j]["total_quantity"] += obj["total_quantity"];
      dupId = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!dupId) {
    ids.push(obj["_id"]);
    merge.push(obj);
  }
}
```

The code will:

- Declare and initialize merge array to an empty array
- Loop through all elements from data array
- And inside, check for duplicate of element in merge array
- If found, add total quantities and total prices
- If not found, add element to merge array